# Retrieve SOAP response

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am writing the code (below) in a `Servlet`. This has to return value in `SOAP Response` but this is not displaying the value from SOAP file. I am not having any error.

I retrieve the `xml` from outside and have inlined it here for ease of reading. Thus I need to be able to parse that result to get out the relevant line.

```
String xmlInput="   <S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
              + " <S:Body>\n"
              + " <ns2:tataResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://pack/\">\n"
              + " <return>12500</return>\n"
              + "  </ns2:tataResponse>\n"
              + " </S:Body>\n"
              + "</S:Envelope>\n";  
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(),
                 new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlInput.getBytes(
                                          Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
NodeList returnList = body.getElementsByTagName("ns2:tataResponse");

boolean isSucces = false;

for (int k = 0; k < returnList.getLength(); k++) {
   NodeList innerResultList = returnList.item(k).getChildNodes();
   for (int l = 0; l < innerResultList.getLength(); l++) {
      if (innerResultList.item(l).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("return")) {
         isSucces = Integer.valueOf(innerResultList.item(l)
                       .getTextContent().trim()) == 100 ? true : false;
      }
   }
}

if (isSucces) {
   NodeList list = body.getElementsByTagName("return");
   for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
       NodeList innerList = list.item(i).getChildNodes();
       for (int j = 0; j < innerList.getLength(); j++) {
          System.out.println(innerList.item(j).getNodeName());
          System.out.println(innerList.item(j).getTextContent());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  You're in a servlet but you're not doing anything with the request or response objects...

Comment: In SOAPResponse <return>12500<return> this value have to display for me from SOAPResponse.@JoeriHendrickx

Comment: (posting as a comment because the question makes no sense)... then just do `processRequest(...){ response.getWriter().println("<return>12500</return>"); }`.

Comment: i dnt want to print directly.i want to retrive <return>12500</return> from SOAPResponse

Comment: I reduced your code to the meaningful elements. Also that this is a Servlet has nothing to do with the problem (which resides in your XML parsing). Please add some markers in the code that show you what happens where and tell us where it goes wrong. Currently I would guess that the first loop is run twice and thus the `isSuccess` is set to false in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The if clause that tests `ifSucces` will never be called because you define that variable to be false. You extracted the result correctly from the XML, but then it is not equal to `100` in this line:

```
isSucces = Integer.valueOf(innerResultList.item(l)
                  .getTextContent().trim()) == 100 ? true : false;
```

And thus `ifSucces` is `false`.

Perhaps if you replace the value `12500` (in your XML) with `100` it will work as you expected.

Comment: i replace 100 as 12500 in java code.after that also i am not getting output

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in code not shown. If you change 12500 to 100 in the XML as helderdarocha said it works. See this:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Foo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String xmlInput="   <S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
              + " <S:Body>\n"
              + " <ns2:tataResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://pack/\">\n"
              + " <return>100</return>\n"
              + "  </ns2:tataResponse>\n"
              + " </S:Body>\n"
              + "</S:Envelope>\n";  
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(),
                 new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(xmlInput.getBytes(
                                          Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
NodeList returnList = body.getElementsByTagName("ns2:tataResponse");

boolean isSucces = false;

for (int k = 0; k < returnList.getLength(); k++) {
   System.out.println("k: " + k);
   NodeList innerResultList = returnList.item(k).getChildNodes();
   for (int l = 0; l < innerResultList.getLength(); l++) {
   String name = innerResultList.item(l).getNodeName();
   System.out.println("l: " + l + ": -" + name + "-");
      if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("return")) {
         String content = innerResultList.item(l).getTextContent().trim();
         System.out.println("content: " + content);
         isSucces = Integer.valueOf(content) == 100 ? true : false;
      }
   }
}

if (isSucces) {
   NodeList list = body.getElementsByTagName("return");
   for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
   System.out.println("i: " + i);
       NodeList innerList = list.item(i).getChildNodes();
       for (int j = 0; j < innerList.getLength(); j++) {
   System.out.println("j: " + j);
          System.out.println(innerList.item(j).getNodeName());
          System.out.println(innerList.item(j).getTextContent());
       }
   }
}
}
}
```

Comment: This is not working.when i run this code i got only blank page